# Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy: "style-src 'self' https://apis.google.com.

Tags: google-signin

cb=gapi.loaded_0:formatted:2677

n.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px; left: -9999px;");

Here is the complete message:

Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://apis.google.com 'sha256-g1S9hiXQ4j0r+GB1Gi3NXXa9uB+5dR2H21SD7BToUKg='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-WuACXZzzdKkWqck4qh4/nDEQy6ZpPTP0wGUXa/3oqT4='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

I don't want to enable 'unsafe-inline'. What are my options? As shown above, it seems I can include only one sha1 hash in my style-src directive. But, I get multiple inline style violations each suggesting its own sha1 hash. May be I am using a wrong syntax to include multiple sha1 hashes? Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: By the way, it's not sha1, it's sha256. CSP allows also using sha384 or sha512.

Comment: Yeah. It was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using their OpenID Connect API since I didn't want to use unsafe-inline. It is more involved to (correctly) implement. Since google injects their code using an iframe, I thought they would quickly fix this issue using a <style> tag in the iframe. I think that would be more convenient for developers in the sense that they don't have to use OpenID Connect. Until that happens, I think OpenID Connect is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that you can specify only one hash - this is not true. You can specify more hashes, e.g.

```
style-src 'self' 'sha256-g1S9hiXQ4j0r+GB1Gi3NXXa9uB+5dR2H21SD7BToUKg=' 'sha256-WuACXZzzdKkWqck4qh4/nDEQy6ZpPTP0wGUXa/3oqT4='
```

The problem is that at least some browsers (Chrome, Safari) apply 'shaXXX' rules to `<style>` elements only, not `style` attributes. See: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=546106

So, what are the options?

- Use `unsafe-inline` (not recommended),
- Rewrite the code to use `<style>` tags and use 'shaXXX' or 'nonce',
- Use a separate style sheet (recommended).

Comment: The problem is gapi.loaded_0 is not my code. It's google's code. So, I can't use suggestions (2) and (3) from you. I figured out that you can add more sha256 hash. But, it will generate the same error with another hash somewhere else in their code.